# How to change colors of multiple texts of the same ID?

Tags: jquery

Basically, what I'm trying to do is change the color for "points" of multiple things on a page. If its positive, I want it to be green and red if its negative. For the point values, I put them in

tags like

```
<p id="points">9843</p>
```

and so far, there's two of them. I got both of them to change color with the following jquery code

```
var $points = $('#points');

if(parseInt($points.html())>0){
    $('#points:first-child').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
}
else{
    $('#points:first-child').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
}
```

However, if one of the numbers is negative while the other is positive, they stay the same color. Not one of them turning red and one staying green like I want. I tried using $(this).removeClass..... and that didn't work either. Is there a selector that would allow to "change the color of the text content of a

```
<p>
```

with an id of #points"?

Comment: Put a class on each of the elements you want to check. Then call by class instead of by ID .

Comment: IDs must be unique in a single document.

Comment: But your element has no `:first-child`; where is the `class` name being applied? Also, as implied earlier, your HTML is invalid: an `id` ***must be unique within the document***, use a `class` instead.

Comment: So you have to put a unique class/id for every point value? I planning on putting 10-30 different point values on my page, is there no easier way to do this?

Comment: I tried changing points from an id to a class....still doesn't work. In the css I changed `#points` to `.points` and in the jquery code I changed `$points = $('#points');` to `$points = $('.points');` along with the add/remove classes to `$('.points').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you change your selector to a class-name, such as `.points`, the following works:

```
// selecting the 'p' elements with the className of 'points':
$('p.points')
// removing both the 'red' and 'green' classNames:
.removeClass('green red')
// using the anonymous function of addClass() to specify which class to add:
.addClass(function(){
    // using $.trim() to remove leading/trailing white-space from the text,
    // if that text is a number greater than 0, we return the 'green' className,
    // otherwise the 'red' className:
    return parseFloat($.trim($(this).text())) > 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wy6ps/).

If you want to ensure the `.points` element(s) contain a number before adding the `green`/`red` classNames:

```
$('p.points').removeClass('green red').addClass(function(i,c){
    var text = parseFloat($.trim($(this).text()));
    // using jQuery.isNumeric() to assess whether the passed variable
    // is, or represents, a number (true if it does, false if it does not):
    if ($.isNumeric(text)) {
        return text > 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wy6ps/2/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Conditional ('ternary') operator: `assessment ? trueCondition : falseCondition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- jQuery:

  - [`$.isNumeric()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/).
  - [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. Man I need to learn up on all them shorthands

Comment: You're very welcome! Incidentally, don't feel pressured to learn at any particular pace; I picked up JavaScript more or less accidentally without really focusing on ít.